# Standard evaluation with mutate_ to calculate percentages by group

Tags: r, dplyr, standard-evaluation

I am trying to use standard evaluation with `dplyr` to calculate percents as a function of two grouping variables. The problem is in my `mutate_ statement`.

Here is a dataset:

```
structure(list(
    var1 = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L
    ), 
    .Label = c("No", "Yes"), class = "factor"), 
    var2 = structure(c(2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L
    ), 
    .Label = c("Female", "Male"), class = "factor")), 
    .Names = c("var1", "var2"), row.names = c(NA, -100L), class = "data.frame")
```

Here is the code I am working with:

```
for_plots = function(data, var1, var2){
  grouped_data = data %>% group_by_(var1, var2) %>% 
  summarise_(n_in_group = ~n()) %>% 
  mutate_(.dots = setNames(list(
    interp(quote(n_in_group / sum(n_in_group, na.rm = TRUE) * 100),
           n_in_group = as.name(n_in_group)))
    ))
  return(grouped_data)
}
```

When I run the code, I receive an error:

> Error in setNames(list(interp(quote(n_in_group/sum(n_in_group, na.rm = TRUE) *  : 
>   argument "nm" is missing, with no default

Any thoughts?

Comment: There is no reason to use SE there. You defined the var name n_in_group within the function and so don't need to treat it as a dynamic input...

Comment: @Frank Thank you. The following code worked:for_plots = function(data, var1, var2){
  grouped_data = data %>% group_by_(var1, var2) %>% 
    summarise_(n_in_group = ~n()) %>% 
    mutate(percent = (n_in_group / sum(n_in_group, na.rm = TRUE)) * 100)
  return(grouped_data )
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is some code based on @Frank's response:

```
for_plots = function(data, var1, var2) { 
   grouped_data = data %>% group_by_(var1, var2) %>% 
     summarise_(n_in_group = ~n()) %>% 
     mutate(percent = (n_in_group / sum(n_in_group, na.rm = TRUE)) * 100) 
   return(grouped_data) 
}
```